# Is it possible to further generalise Brahmagupta's identity?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Is it possible to generalise [Brahmagupta's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_identity)

further, by which I mean, for different n, for example take the equations:

$$1357 = 37^2 - 3\times2^2$$

$$1357 = 38^2 - 87\times1^2$$

$$1357^2 = 1841449 = 3445^2 - 261\times196^2$$

Is there an algebraic route between the first two and the third?

Comment: Avoid the use of $∗$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics where it has other meanings. Use `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or `\times` ($\times$).

Comment: @jjagmath There is nothing at all wrong with using such notation. It is also used widely in mathematics.

Comment: Not quite in the spirit of Brahmagupta, there may be something more to the observation that $196=14^2$ and $3445=41^2+42^2$, where $42=3\times14$.

Comment: @BillDubuque I search in about 10 textbooks of Mathematics, didn't find it. Then look in about 10 research articles, same result. Then I looked in several Wikipedia pages and find it in one, which say "In computer programming, the asterisk (as in 5*2) is still the most common notation."

Comment: @jjagmath If you peruse older papers (composed before $\TeX$ existed, e.g. on typewriters) you should find plently of examples - esp. at more elementary levels (where there is far less need to reserve $\,*\,$ for other abstract operations). The use of $\,*\,$ for multiplication [originated in](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathsym/operation/) J. Rahn's algebra textbook *Teutsche Algebra* (1659), which also introduced the obelus $\,\div\,$ for division.

Comment: @BillDubuque And if you look at some old books you'll find the notation $| \underline{n}$ to denote the factorial of $n$, but if I find someone using it this century I will still discourage it, even if it's a notation that preceded the modern one.

Comment: @jjagmath Poor analogies aside, the fact of the matter is that star notation for multplication is still use in mathematical literature (though not as wide as it once was in the past), and no one will misunderstand what it means, so there is no problem using it if one so desires.

Answer (score 2):

No, I wouldn't think so. It would be easy enough if $3 \cdot 87$  were a square, this is called composition in different orders in Buell's book.

As $261$  is not a square: if there were some nice way to  combine things, we could expect to take

$$ 2^2 - 3 \cdot 1^2 = 1 \; , \; \; \;  28^2 - 87 \cdot 3^2 = 1 $$

and quickly solve $x^2 - 261 y^2 = 1^2 = 1$  in fairly small numbers. However, the smallest such is

$$ 192119201^2 - 261 \cdot 11891880^2 = 1 $$

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it is (very) unlikely. Though maybe not impossible.